# Java Regex, matching paragraph starting with x, ending with y

Tags: java, regex, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to use the scanner.next(Pattern p) method to pick out parts of a large text file which start with the word bob and end with the word jim. For example:

```
hello hello jimbob jimhellohellobob hellojim hellobob
```

would `next()` three times, returning `"jimbob"`, `"jimhellohellobob"`, and `"jim hellobob"`

but preferably not `"jimbob jimhellohellobob hellojim hellobob"` i.e. it excludes the word 'jim' in the allowed text between the start and end.

I suck at Regex, let alone Java regex so I'm not having much luck. This is where I'm at at the moment:

```
String test = "hello hello jimbob jimhellohellobob hellojim hellobob ";


    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*jim.*bob.*");
    Scanner s = new Scanner(test);
    String temp;

    while(s.hasNext(p)){
        temp = s.next(p);
        System.out.println(temp);
    }
```

This isn't printing out anything. Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: A word usually means a character sequence delimited by whitespace. In your example `jim` and `bob` are not words, rather character sequences (ie. they don't need to be on word boundaries. Please update your question replacing the word _word_ with _character sequence_.

Answer (score 3):

You are using wrong class. To find all occurrences or regex you need to use `Matcher` and its `find` method. Also your current regex thanks to `.*` at start and end accepts any string which *contains* `jim` and `bob`. Also `.*` is greedy so for data like `hello jimbob hello bob` pattern `jim.*bob*` will match `jimbob hello bob` instead of only `jimbob` part. To make `.*` [reluctant](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy) you need to add `?` after it like `.*?`.

So your code should look more like

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("jim.*?bob"); //depending on what you want you may 
                                          //also need to add word boundary `\\b`
Matcher m = p.matcher(yourText);
while(m.find()){
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much. This is at least giving me something now. Could you explain the ? symbol a bit more? I still have a situation where jimjimbob is being matched...

Comment: @DuaneAllman I updated my answer with link to article about `.*?`.

Comment: @DuaneAllman also can you explain why `jimjimbob` is wrong result? What exactly do you want to find? Do you want to find single word of text fragment. Should `foo jim bar bob baz` return any results like `jim bar bob` or none since it doesn't contain single words which start with `jim` and end with `bob`?